# Nullpointer exception on initialized array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I created a class called IntegerSet which is basically just an array of Booleans. I have declared and initialized all the Boolean values to be false. When I try to use my insertion function, I get a null pointer exception, which is odd because in my constructor I initialize all the booleans to false, so there should be no null values.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class IntegerSet
 {
     private final static int size = 101;
     private Boolean[] myArray;

     IntegerSet(){
         Boolean[] myArray = new Boolean[size];
         for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
            myArray[i] = new Boolean(false);
         }
    }

     public IntegerSet insertElement(int data){
            this.myArray[data] = true;
            return this;
      }
 }
```

And the main that calls the object's relevant code:

```
public class HW2Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IntegerSet set1 = new IntegerSet();
        IntegerSet set2 = new IntegerSet();

        set1.insertElement(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify the duplicate a little, `Boolean[] myArray = new Boolean[size];` declares a new `myArray` variable and initializes that, the `myArray` declared in the class is still left unchanged as null.

Comment: even clearer : replace ``Boolean[] myArray = new Boolean[size];`` by ``myArray = new Boolean[size];`` ;-)